# strange rendering on objects touching each other

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have several threejs objects in a scene.
When they come close to or touching each other, I see strange triangular artifacts at the object borders, as to be seen in the picture below.

renderer is THREE.WebGLRenderer 103

What could cause this?

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: We will not be able to help you much unless you post the actual code and any supporting HTML to reproduce this here.

Comment: This is part of a huge project, I will try to extract some meaningful code snippets. I thought there might be some general ideas like renderer settings, THREEjs documentation does not tell much about what could be helpful here.

Comment: @fwerre You don't need to re-create the huge project. Just use a small [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to re-create with a minimal example. It might be that you're experiencing [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting), although it's hard to tell from that screenshot.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Z-fighting sounds like a promising explananation. The objects in the scene reflect real-world objects and the positions are real-world positions. The scale is 1:1, units are Millimeter so the range is from 0 to ca. 200000 (aka 200 Meters). If objects stand as close as 50cm (500 units apart), Z-fighting appears like a good reason. The scale could not easily being changed, so whatcould be a solution? Increasing depth buffer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing z-fighting, a possibility suggested by @Marquizzo in a comment, it may help to reduce the range of the camera, so that it gets higher depth resolution in the critical area.

```
camera.near = largestAcceptable;
camera.far = smallestAcceptable;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already limit the clipping planes to the minimum possible range, but, as said in my other comment above, I must reflect real-world distances from 200000 Millimeters

Comment: If you cannot reduce the far distance, you may still afford increasing the near distance, e.g. to 100 millimeters.